# GuideWire BC configuration with SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server, guidewire

Currently working on PC-BC integration. I need to configure my studios with SQL Server database, For PC its working fine, but for BC I'm getting error. If anyone knows please help me to sort this out.

```
  <database name="BillingCenterDatabase" dbtype="sqlserver" autoupgrade="true">
    <dbcp-connection-pool jdbc-url="jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;DatabaseName=BillingCenterDatabase;User=username;Password=pass#1121"/>
    <upgrade defer-create-nonessential-indexes="false">
      <versiontriggers dbmsperfinfothreshold="600" />
    </upgrade>
  </database>
```

- my username is "username" and password is "pass#1121"
- database name : BillingCenterDatabase

The error which I'm getting is

> gw.pl.exception.GWLifecycleException: No appropriate database found in configuration: env = 'null'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try adding environment attribute in your database tag like shown below,

```
  <database name="BillingCenterDatabase" dbtype="sqlserver" env="dev" autoupgrade="true">
<dbcp-connection-pool jdbc-url="jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;DatabaseName=BillingCenterDatabase;User=username;Password=pass#1121"/>
<upgrade defer-create-nonessential-indexes="false">
  <versiontriggers dbmsperfinfothreshold="600" />
</upgrade>
```

Answer (score 2):

You should have to mention environment name in tomcat.conf in tomcat config file if you are deploying your application on tomcat.

JAVA_OPTS="-Dgw.server.mode=dev **-Dgw.bc.env=st**"

above line for st environment. you need to enter ut/st/st2 for different environment.